# Will strong base corrode aluminium in absence of oxygen?

Tags: oxidation-state, corrosion

From what i understand, putting iron in a vacuum chamber (airtight container) will stops further oxidation take place.

However in aluminium, with only oxygen, aluminium will form thin oxide film that will stops further oxidation take place.

I wonder if aluminium can be put into vacuum chamber to prevent corrosion take place, even if submerged in strong acid/base solution?

My assumption it won't, because of oxygen and acid/base is different oxidation agent

But i could be wrong

Comment: Vacuum and water solutions do not like each other.

Comment: Oxygen is irrelevant to the reaction between aluminium and strong bases. It is relevant to passive protection of aluminium but bases corrode away the passivating layer. Consider, for example, the process of making Raney Nickel. A NiAl alloy is reacted with a strong base like sodium hydroxide which dissolves the Al leaving very finely divided, high surface area nickel. In labs this is usually done with the exclusion of air because the product is pyrophoric. But the Al still dissolves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approximately 0.01 hour of searching, including the time taken to type in the search words, reveals this on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium):

> In hot concentrated hydrochloric acid, aluminium reacts with water with evolution of hydrogen, and in aqueous sodium hydroxide or potassium hydroxide at room temperature to form aluminates—protective passivation under these conditions is negligible.[1]

So water with a strong nonoxidizing acid or base, but otherwise isolated, will corrode aluminum.

**Cited Reference**

1.
Beal, Roy E. (1999). *Engine Coolant Testing : Fourth Volume.* ASTM International. p. 90. ISBN 978-0-8031-2610-7. Archived from the original on 24 April 2016.

Comment: Do you mean the potassium hydroxide will still corrode aluminum, even in absence of oxygen? Pardon for my limited english, your sentence structure a bit difficult for me to understand clearly

Comment: Water with strong acid or base does not need oxygen to corrode aluminum.

Comment: If that's the case I wonder if there is any way to stop further corrosion of aluminum when it's dipped in strong acid/base solution?

Comment: @digda  the way to stop corrosion of aluminium by strong acid/base is to not dip it in the solution

Comment: OK, a reference noting: "protective passivation under these conditions is negligible.[1]", which supports  the term "dissolving", and not "corroding".

Answer (score -2):

Actually, the question is correct in citing the seeming "corroding" and not dissolving of "Aluminum" in the context of a strong base, like Lime (Calcium hydroxide), which is apparently commonly attacking Aluminum alloy structures, for example, from the release of CaO dust from cement plants.

For example, see [this question](https://www.finishing.com/384/92.shtml), to quote:

> I have a question, when our aluminum tank coverings for upright storage tanks were exposed to Lime from a cement plant they all turned black. What is the reaction here and what if anything can we do to protect the tank coverings?

Apparently, the net reaction is given by:

> $\ce{Ca(OH)2 + Al(s) + 8 H2O = Ca3Al2((OH)4)3 + 6 H2 }$

where $\ce{Ca3Al2((OH)4))3}$ is known as Katoite, which per a [mineral source](https://www.mindat.org/min-2167.html), to quote:

> This progressive exchange can also be represented as Ca3Al2(SiO4)3-x(OH)4x. In end-member katoite, the replacement is complete (so x = 3).

Wikipedia further notes:

> Hydrogrossular is translucent to opaque, and found in green to bluish green, pink, white, and gray. The cause of the green color is chromium, and possibly iron. Pink hydrogrossular is caused by the presence of manganese. Hydrogrossular may have dark gray to black small inclusions.[1].

The "Aluminum" as referenced here is likely an alloy with several elements, to quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_alloy):

> The typical alloying elements are copper, magnesium, manganese, silicon, tin and zinc.

So, to answer the question a seeming corrosion with a dark coating is possible and chemically not dependent on the presence of oxygen.